# How much quicker is public instance variable access compared to properties in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, performance, oop, properties

My company finishing up a new game engine which (like most engines) is very CPU intensive. It is written in Objective-C and most of the core game items which get accessed frequently are stored in object properties. Most of these are automatically synthesized and are simply stored and read.

How much speed, if any, would we gain by changing properties in the core game engine items to be public instance variables?

So whereas it would be declared and accessed like this with a property

```
@property (nonatomic) CMLocation location;
node.location.x;
```

It would now be:

```
@public:
   CMLocation location
node->location->x
```

Logically speaking, I think ivars would be much faster as it should be an almost single clock tick operation (assuming no cache miss), but perhaps the compiler tunes that sort of thing out now and synthesized properties are just as fast.

Comment: Benchmark it.  If the speed is acceptable, stick with properties.  Clarity of code is important too.

Comment: An atomic property like you are declaring there will definitely be slower than an ivar

Comment: Thanks, I changed it to non-atomic as that is actually how we use it.

Comment: Public instance variables is a bad idea. Don't make internal implementation details public.

Comment: Strikes me as a possible "premature optimization". Be wary of optimizing code for theoretical optimizations, sacrificing the maintainability of the code. Sure, if this was an actual bottleneck, then make this sacrifice, but this is unlikely to be the case here. And if you're calling this so often that it did have any observable impact, then the problem probably rests in the broader design, not in this accessor. But only reviewing this in a broader context and benchmarking your code will verify this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't answer in numbers, but try to describe mechanics "under the hood"

When we access property via `node->location->x` - it the fastest way, just address lookup in memory, pure c-style.

When we access via `node.location.x`, obj-c calls getter method for the property, and it's not just classic function call - obj-c performs `objc_msgSend( node, @selector( location))`, which performs selector look-up by string name. You can find pretty clear description of this process here: https://www.mulle-kybernetik.com/artikel/Optimization/opti-3.html

So, if your code is executed pretty often and it's a bottleneck for performance - yes, you should rewrite it to c-style. Also, keep in mind that struct properties are accessed directly, and when rewriting pay attention to safety - you don't have `nil` check anymore.

P.S. You can measure performance to find bottlenecks with Instruments and optimize just important code blocks - it's wise approach for optimization.